# How can i remove the region in TYPO3 9 SEO extension from hreflang

Tags: typo3, seo, typo3-9.x, hreflang

In a customer project we use the SEO Extension from TYPO3 9.
It creates automatically the hreflang tags for us.

But how can I remove the region from the hreflang tags?

IT LOOKS LIKE THIS

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-DE" href="https://stage.customer.com/de/"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="https://stage.customer.com/en/"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://stage.customer.com/de/"/>
```

IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE THAT

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://stage.customer.com/de/"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://stage.customer.com/en/"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://stage.customer.com/de/"/>
```

If I seach the SEO Extension for simple de-DE I find nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EXT:seo fetches that from your site config, under languages › Frontend related:

[image: site configuration]